# Find user’s session in RDS

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019

Let’s say I have a Remote Desktop Services environment with two connection brokers and four Remote Desktop Session Hosts.

I want to know which of the four session hosts that user jdoe is logged on to.

How can I retrieve this information using Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Get-RDUserSession](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/remotedesktop/get-rdusersession), like that:

```perl
Import-Module RemoteDesktop
Get-RDUserSession | where {$_.UserName -eq "jdoe"} | Select HostServer
```

Comment: For those finding this from a Google search, this will need to be run with administrative permissions or it will not work.